# Integer Value Problem

Tags: c++, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I pad an int with leading zeros when using cout << operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714515/how-can-i-pad-an-int-with-leading-zeros-when-using-cout-operator)

How could I show 01 in an integer?

whenever I convert a string to integer, I always get 1 instead of 01.

How could get a 01 value.

Comment: What's the usage of getting a 01 value in int? what's difference between this and 1, in int operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged it as C++, the way to do it with C++'s streams could be the following:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {    
    int value = 1;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.width(2);
    ss << std::setfill('0') << value;

    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl; // displays '01'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't confuse the value that's *stored* with the way you want it *presented.*

You can just use:

```
std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << 1;
```

as shown in the following complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    int x = 1;
    std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
01
```

Answer (score 1):

The `integer` type uses all its memory - typically 32 or 64 bits - to cover the largest possible range of distinct integer values it can.  It doesn't keep track of any formatting/display information.  Consequently, even a 32-bit value can track some 4 billion distinct values, but however they're to be shown on-screen, in files etc. has to be decided by the surrounding code, and is not a property of the `integer` itself.  So, if you have an integer, you can choose the formatting when you display it.  There are a variety of ways to do this.  The most C++ way is using `std::ostream` and the `<iomanip>` header, which includes support for specifying a field width and fill/padding character.  For an example, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setw/ and you can follow the "See also" link to setfill.  The way inherited from C is...

```
printf("%02d", n);
```

...where the first double-quoted string section contains a "format string", in which % introduces a conversion, 0 means to pad and 2 is the width, d means the next decimal/integer value in the list of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using printf, use the following formate specifier

```
printf("%02d\n",myInt);
```

Here, the 0 after percentage indicates leading zero padding and 2 indicates a field width of 2.

Answer (score 0):

As an integer, it will always be 1,
You can only display 01 when you turn it back into a String for display purposes.

The best way would be to use the printf

```
printf("%02d", x);
```

Answer (score 0):

When displaying the value using a formatter you can write:

```
%02d
```

See the C++ reference documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/