# Printing 0 as hex in operator<<

Tags: c++

Here is a code sample that I am using to print the contents of a `uint8_t` vector in hex format.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const std::vector<uint8_t>& packet) {
    std::ios_base::fmtflags oldFlags = o.flags();
    std::streamsize oldPrec  = o.precision();
    char oldFill  = o.fill();

    o << std::showbase // show the 0x prefix
      << std::internal // fill between the prefix and the number
      << std::setfill('0'); // fill with 0s

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < packet.size(); ++i) {
        o << std::setw(4) << std::hex << (int) packet[i] << " ";
    }

    o.flags(oldFlags);
    o.precision(oldPrec);
    o.fill(oldFill);

    return o;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<uint8_t> packet{0x81, 0x55, 0x00};
    std::cout << packet << "\n";
}
```

This prints the following:

> 0x81 0x55 0000

I want that last `0000` to show up as `0x00`. How can I achieve this?

PS: I looked at couple of questions regarding printing `0x00` but answers on those questions prints `0000` for me as well.

Comment: There's the obvious way `if (packet[i] == 0) o << "0x00" ...`, but I'm surprised that's necessary. Is this a bug?

Comment: try  `cout << "0x" << setfill('0') << setw(2) << hex << 00 << endl;` from https://stackoverflow.com/q/5760252/4848659

Comment: The issue is discussed here  [std::showbase fails for hex value 0](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=166735)

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513169/why-is-0-zero-printed-without-leading-0x-with-c-printf-format-x#8513429

Comment: I went with doing something special for 0, as indicated by other questions also given here. I asked this to see if there is a uniform way but does not seem to be the case.