# Incremeting integer precision in C++ before the decimal point (e.g. 7 --> 007)

Tags: c++, integer, precision

Yes you read that right, Im looking for a way of incrementing integer's precision *before* the decimal point. The reason is irrelevant and would be long to explain. Specifically, I want to increment it to the hundreds, for instance:

- 1 --> 001
- 7 --> 007
- 27 --> 027
- 358 --> 358

...and so on and so forth.

Im aware there's a way of just programing this, but I presume there's a way of doing this automatically, am I right? Just like the "setprecision()" command, but the way around as you can see. I've looked up for this a long time but all previous questions just regard the precision after the decimal point.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me in this weird request.

Comment: Looks like `setfill` and `setw` would work.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714515/how-can-i-pad-an-int-with-leading-zeros-when-using-cout-operator. In your searching, you want to use the terms "zero padding".

Comment: Oh, sorry for making a duplicate question guys, seems like I didn't use the proper terms when searching. Anyway, thanks for the tip, that certainly makes it much easier than programing it.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote something like this a short while back.

I'm not saying this is perfect but you get the idea.

Use recursion:

```
int someNumber = 235;
int number = someNumber;
int minDigits = 5;
int actualDigits = 0;

string intString = "";

int digitCount = 0;

while (number > 0)
{
    number /= 10;
    actualDigits ++;
}

intString = itoa( someNumber );

while (actualDigits < minDigits)
{
    intString = string("0") + intString;
    actualDigits++;
}
```

now `intString` will be `"00235"`

Comment: Thanks for the program, thats more or less what I was thinking with programing, although what I was looking for was setfill and setw.