# C++ function to return current date (with zeros in month and day)

Tags: c++, function, date, zero

I have this C++ function:

```
string date()
{
  time_t seconds = time (NULL);

struct tm * timeinfo = localtime (&seconds);

ostringstream oss;
oss << (timeinfo->tm_year + 1900) << "-" << (timeinfo->tm_mon + 1) << "-" << timeinfo->tm_mday; 
string data = oss.str();

return data;
}
```

The problem is I wanted the month and day with 0's. It's returning '2013-6-1' instead of '2013-06-01'

I'm trying to get this right with some if's and else's but I'm not getting anywhere..

Could you please help me?

Comment: I suggest to use `boost::format`.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714515/how-can-i-pad-an-int-with-leading-zeros-when-using-cout-operator

Comment: Read about `strftime`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the two stream modifiers [`std::setw`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/) and [`std::setfill`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setfill/) with appropriate settings, for instance you can change your code to read:

```
string date()
{
   time_t seconds = time (NULL);

   struct tm * timeinfo = localtime (&seconds);

   ostringstream oss;
   oss << (timeinfo->tm_year + 1900) << "-" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (timeinfo->tm_mon + 1) << "-" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << timeinfo->tm_mday; 
   string data = oss.str();

   return data;
}
```

Comment: Remember to `#include <iomanip>` to use these output modifiers

Comment: That did it!
Thank you very much to all!

Answer (score 0):

You can also [use std::put_time](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time), though not implemented in gcc 4.7:

```
std::string date()
{
    time_t seconds = time (NULL);
    struct tm * timeinfo = localtime (&seconds);
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::put_time(&timeinfo, "%Y-%m-%d");
    // or: oss << std::put_time(&timeinfo, "%F");
    return oss.str();
}
```

Comment: And in C++11 (which is required for `std::put_time` anyway), you can use `%F`.