# set precision of digits before the decimal point?

Tags: c++, precision, cout, iomanip

I have already viewed this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714515/how-can-i-pad-an-int-with-leading-zeros-when-using-cout-operator) but it does not account for using negative numbers if i use setfill( '0' ).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    //Code
    int num1;

    cin >> num1;

    cout << setw(5) << setfill( '0' ) << num1 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Using this method if I enter a "5" it will display as "00005".
But if I enter a -5 it will display as "000-5"

How can I fix it so that the out put will be "-0005" ?

Comment: That's why I still prefer the printf() mask format. %05d just does the right thing.

Comment: @epx And once you change the type of the variable to `short` for whatever reason, your version is broken. However, since C++11 a type-safe alternative can be realized, such as [this library](https://github.com/c42f/tinyformat)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "fill character" is used to fill up the field to the specified width. By default, these characters are added to the left, such that the output will be *right* aligned. You can use `std::left` for *left* alignment. For numbers, the additional option [`std::internal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) will fill the space *between the sign and the actual digits*:

```
cout << setw(5) << setfill('0') << internal << -42 << endl;
```

http://ideone.com/Pdsz3M

Comment: Is this C++11 or C++03 compatible?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Works with both standards.