# Return integer value as string for date formatting

Tags: c++, string, int

I have function that has three integer values, representing year, month and day. I want to return these values with dashes '-' in between, as in common date format.

e.g.:

```
int main() {
    cout << myfunction() << endl; // this should display like this 2014-04-15
}

string myfunction() {
    int year = 2014;
    int month = 04;
    int day = 15;
    // I want to return this value like this
    return year-month-day;//2014-04-15
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Take a look at [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

Comment: All the replies given so far misses the problem of 0-padding (e.g. April -> 4 -> output `04`). [It's very easy and clear to do that with `sprintf()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23091285/1629821); it's a bit more work with `<sstream>` string streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++03 you can use `std::ostringstream` class to format a string using `operator<<` :

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string myfunction() {
    int year=2014;
    int month=04;
    int day=15;

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << year << "-" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') 
                                                     << month << "-" << day;
    return oss.str();
           ^^^^^^^^^ // this will yield a formatted string that oss contains
}
```

In C++11 you can use [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) and `operator+` to concatenate strings:

```
#include <string>

std::string myfunction() {
    int year=2014;
    int month=04;
    int day=15;

    std::string s = to_string( year) 
                    + "-" + to_string(month)
                    + "-" + to_string(day);
    return s;
}
```

however `to_string` doesn't offer formatting option. If you want to specify format, again, you should look into string stream.

Comment: Are you sure the OP wants to print April as `4`, or would `04` be better?

Comment: changed to print zeroes, thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe the second code with `to_string()` needs a fix as well?

Comment: added the note about formatting to_string, thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
```

...

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << year << "-"
   << std::setw(2) << month << "-" << std::setw(2) << day;
return ss.str();
```

Comment: Are you sure the OP wants to print April as `4`, or would `04` be better?

Comment: @Mr.C64 thanks. I edited the answer based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

also, if you don't have C++11, look at boost::lexical_cast(...), or if you don't want boost, look at stringstream.

```
stringstream ss;
ss << first << "-" << second << "-" << third << endl;
return ss.str();
```

that have to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
ostringstream oss;
oss << year << '-' << month << '-' << day;

return oss.str();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a string stream.

```
string myfunction(){
    int year=2014;
    int month=04;
    int day=15;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << year << "-" << month << "-" << day;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Don't forget to include `sstream` header.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use STL, you can also resort to C-style function _itoa. Here is a link to the documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yakksftt.aspx

But I do suggest you to use stringstream like others are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Even in C++ code, I like `printf`-like format specifiers (in this case, to be used with `sprintf()`).

You may want to consider this compilable code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string ToString(int year, int month, int day) {
    char buffer[11];
    // YYYY-MM-DD
    // 1234567890
    //          10 + NUL --> 11 characters in buffer

    sprintf(buffer, "%04d-%02d-%02d", year, month, day);
    // sprintf_s on MSVC would be better (and it implicitly gets the dest buffer size).

    return buffer;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << ToString(2014, 4, 15) << std::endl;
}
```

Output is `2014-04-15`, as requested.

---

**PS**
If you want to use C++ string streams (from `<sstream>`), then you should pay attention to *padding* with a leading `0` the months and days having one digit. For that purpose, consider [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1714515/1629821) and related answers. The key point is to use `setfill('0')` and `setw(2)` for padding.