# How to include a leading zero when converting seconds to minutes and the remainder is less than 10 seconds?

Tags: c++

My function turns seconds to minutes.  The problem is, if I have a number where the remainder is less than 10, it will just give give me remainder without a 0 before the remainder.

For example,

- 368 seconds would just turn to `6:8`
- 360 would turn to `6:0`
- 361 to `6:1`

I would like

- 368 seconds to turn to `6:08`
- 360 to `6:00`
- 361 to `6:01`

```
void toMinutesAndSeconds(int inSeconds, int &outMinutes, int &outSeconds) {
    outMinutes = inSeconds / 60;
    outSeconds = inSeconds % 60;
}
```

I'm outputting to a text file.

Comment: Do you output minutes/seconds to console? If so, how do you do that?

Comment: You want to "pad" the number with zeroes. Search for zero-padding. (or prefixing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pad an int with leading zeros when using cout << operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714515/how-can-i-pad-an-int-with-leading-zeros-when-using-cout-operator)

Comment: The code you've shown is correct. The problem is in the code you haven't shown, i.e., in the code that **converts** the numeric value to text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a matter of how you output your values. That value itself doesn't have "leading zeros".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void toMinutesAndSeconds(int inSeconds, int &outMinutes, int &outSeconds) 
{
    outMinutes = inSeconds / 60;
    outSeconds = inSeconds % 60;
}

int main() 
{
    int minutes = 0;
    int seconds = 0;
    toMinutesAndSeconds(368, minutes, seconds);
    std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << minutes << ":"
        << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << seconds;
    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
06:08
```