# Convert 1 to 01 in C++ without using function

Tags: c++

```
int a;
std::cout<<"Enter hour: ";
std::cin>>a;
std::cout<< a;
```

This is just for question purpose. Is there any trick to output 01 instead of 1 without using a function? Suppose if the input is 9 I want 09 to be an output but if the 'a' is 2 digit there is no need to add 0.

Comment: `std::cout << '0' << a;`

Comment: Either do what @WilliamPursell said, or perhaps use something in `<iomanip>`

Comment: You'll have to describe your problem further. What happens if `a = 10` or `100`, for instance? Is this decimal, binary, hex or what, etc.

Comment: Something precision maybe?

Comment: @KenY-N I corrected the question.

Comment: Dup of [How can I pad an int with leading zeros when using cout << operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1714538/1270789).

Comment: @KenY-N I asked if it can be done without using any predefined functions.

Comment: If it's less than 10, print a 0 first. https://ideone.com/ovVT2P

Comment: No. You are using operator `<<`, which is already a predefined function, which in turn calls a lot of other predefined functions.

Comment: @Bibek --  How far are you going to go with not using "predefined functions"?  As pointed out `operator <<` is a predefined function, as well as `operator >>`.  It is very rare to find a C++program written just using straight out C++ syntax with no calls (whether implicit or explicit) to library functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want:

```
std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << a;
```

This sets the field width to 2 and the fill character to `'0'`.  Keep in mind, however, that although the field width is reset after outputting `a`, the fill is not.  So if this is temporary, be sure to save the fill before setting it.

BTW these function are in "iomanip" library

Comment: Is there any way to do it without using pre-defined functions?

Comment: No, as `operator<<` is a pre-defined function.

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
std::cout << ((a <= 9) ? 0 : "") << a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fine Boost.Format library to format the output with printf-like syntax.

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << boost::format("%02d") % 1 << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
#include <iomanip>
```

```
ans=1;
cout<<setw(2)<<setfill('0')<<ans<<endl;
```

OUTPUT: 01