# Please help me print the hundreds digit in reverse order

Tags: c++, reverse, iostream

I want to compare the size of two numbers and print the larger value in reverse.
but, the output value is different from what I expected.

```
#include<iostream>
int main() {
    int a, b;
    int big;
    std::cin >> a>>b;
    if (a > b)
        big = a;
    if (a <= b)
        big = b;
    std::cout << "input" << a <<" "<< b<<"\n";
    std::cout << "bigger"<<big << "\n";
    
    int q, w, e;
    e = big % 10;
    w = (big % 100)-e;
    q= big - (e)-(w * 10);
    std::cout << e << w << q;
    return 0;
}
```

1. This code receives two integers from the user and stores them in variables a and b.
2. It compare two values and store the larger value in the variable called “bigger” by using if statement.
3. Store the remainder of division by 10 in q
   The remainder of division by 100 minus q is stored in w
   Subtract q and 10 times w from the value stored in 'bigger' and store the result in 'e'.
4. Output value of e,w,q without spaces.

there is some example that I expected.
input
`123 456`
output
`123 456 input123456 bigger456 654`

but this is the result.
`123 456 input123 456 bigger456 650-50`

I searched this question.
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529424/traverse-a-list-in-reverse-order-in-python)
It shows How to print a number backwards with a built-in function.
So I asked new question.

Comment: I think you need to divide `w` by ten. You should use more meaningful variable names, especially if you want others (or even yourself) to understand your code

Comment: Learn about std::vector<int> + std::reverse, or reverse iterators (or reverse view C++20).

Comment: You're more likely to succeed if you follow the naming given by the instructions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I simply write a program to reverse a number but the output not meet my expectation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74404280/i-simply-write-a-program-to-reverse-a-number-but-the-output-not-meet-my-expectat)

Comment: My dupe is not a perfect match, but my answer to the question provides three working samples to reverse a number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::to_string` to convert a number to a string.

Then `std::reverse` to reverse the string.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

...

std::string big_s = std::to_string(big);
std::reverse(big_s.begin(), big_s.end());
std::cout << big_s;
```

Answer (score -2):

there is a problem with the calculation of w. In the current code, w is calculated as (big % 100) - e, which only works if e is always a single digit. However, if e is a two-digit number (i.e., if the last two digits of big are the same), then w will be negative.
To fix this issue, you can modify the calculation of w to extract the last two digits of big and subtract e from them.

---

try this

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a, b;
    int big;
    std::cin >> a >> b;
    if (a > b)
        big = a;
    if (a <= b)
        big = b;
    std::cout << "input: " << a << " " << b << "\n";
    std::cout << "bigger: " << big << "\n";

    int q, w, e;
    e = big % 10;
    w = (big / 10) % 10; // Extract the second-to-last digit of big
    q = big / 100; // Extract the first digit of big
    std::cout << e << w << q << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `e` can only be `0`-`9`, `w` can't be negative as `big % 100 >= big % 10`

Comment: Why did you include ```using namespace std;```? This is bad programming practice.

Comment: @user438383 sorry my mistake. next time i will remmber this small things